# jQuery / elements automatically hidden on load

Tags: html, jquery, css

Im working on a **.net web api SINGLE-PAGE app** assignment. Im currently having issues on my client side working with **jQuery**.

My `index.cshtml` has a grid with few `<div>` elements such as `loginDiv`, `registerDiv`, `dataDiv`, `searchDiv`, `logoutDiv` (note that these are also their element `#id`'s).  What im trying to do is hide specific elements once the user enters my `index` page. All my  elements are by default visible so im using `.hide()` method in my script for elements i dont want to be seen.

This is what my `scrtip.js` looks like so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var host = "http://" + window.location.host + "/";
    var festivalsEndPoint = "api/festivali";
    var registerEndPoint = "api/Account/Register";
    var loginEndPoint = "Token";

    var formAction = "POST";
    var editingId;

    var token = null;
    var headers = {};
     
    
    $("#searchDiv").hide();
    $("#createEditDiv").hide();
    $("#logoutDiv").hide();


    $("body").ready(function () {
       
        loadAll();

    });

    function loadAll() {
        
        var requestUrl = host + festivalsEndPoint;
        $.getJSON(requestUrl, fillData);

        var dropdownUrl = host + "api/mesta";
        $.getJSON(dropdownUrl, fillDropDown);
    }
});
```

My `index.cshtml`:

```
@section Scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/script.js")
}

<div class="main-container">

    <div class="grid-container">

        <div id="header" class="item1"><h1>My project</h1></div>

        <div id="registerDiv" class="item2" >
            <p class="form-title"><b>Register form</b></p>
            <form id="registerForm" method="post" action="post/">
                <p>
                    <label>E-mail</label>
                    <input id="registerEmail" type="text">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input id="registerPsw" type="password">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Confirm password</label>
                    <input id="registerPswConfirm" type="password">
                </p>
                <button id="registerBtn" type="submit">Register</button>
                <p id="registrationSuccessful"><b>Registration was successful! You can now log-in...</b> </p>


            </form>
        </div>


        <div id="loginDiv" class="item3">
            <p class="form-title"><b>Login form</b></p>

            <form id="loginForm" method="post" action="post/">
                <p>
                    <label>E-mail</label>
                    <input id="loginEmail" type="text">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input id="loginPsw" type="password">
                </p>
                <button id="loginBtn" type="submit">Sign-in</button>
            </form>
        </div>


        <div id="dataDiv" class="item4">

        </div>


        <div id="logoutDiv" class="item5">
            <p class="form-title"><b>Account</b></p>
            <p id="loggedUser">Logged in user: testtest@gmail.com</p>
            <p><button id="logoutBtn" class="btn-danger">Logout</button></p>

        </div>


        <div id="searchDiv" class="item7">
            <p class="form-title"><b>Search</b></p>
            <form id="searchForm" method="post" action="post/">
                <p>
                    <label>Criterium 1</label>
                    <input type="text">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Criterium 1</label>
                    <input type="password">
                </p>

                <button id="searchBtn" type="submit">Search</button>


            </form>
        </div>

        <div id="createEditDiv" class="item6">
            <p class="form-title"></p>Create / edit form
            <form id="createEditForm" method="post" action="post/">
                <p class="form-title">Form</p>
                <p>
                    <label>Something </label>
                    <input id="" type="text">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Something</label>
                    <input id="" type="text">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Something</label>
                    <input id="" type="text">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <select id="select">  </select>
                </p>

                <button id="submitBtn" type="submit">Submit</button>

            </form>
        </div>

        <!-- GRID -->
    </div>

</div>
```

I've done similar assignment and this approach worked just fine. And now, the **problem** is, once i load the page, the only  element shown is the one with `#logoutDiv` id even though im hiding it in my script. And other elements that are not hidden by default, such as `#loginDiv` and `#registerDiv` are automatically hidden on page load.

**Note**: When i load the page and go to browser console, it even says there are hidden elements. [Click here to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wptcc.png).
I tried to **inspect** the page and in the console it says "`style=display:none`" for the elements that im actually trying not to hide.

**Note**:  I tried deleting my `.css` file from the project to see if my css is casuing this, but the result is same even without any .css

Does anybody know what can cause this? So far i've only tried to give all the elements/divs a `display:none` style, and then use `.show()` in jQuery script, but that doesnt solve my issue.

Comment: Hi @Context can we see your HTML markup as well? A link to a jsfiddle.net or codepen.io would be really great, too.

Comment: The problem with show then hide in js is that you get FOUC - ie you see the separate divs for a (split-)second while the pages is loading.  Always (where possible...) hide in the HTML style then show as needed.

Comment: Your image of the browser console with "4 hidden" is **4 console messages are hidden**, not 4 div elements are hidden.  Click the cog to unhide them, maybe there's something important in there.

Comment: What does this give you?  `console.log($("[id=logoutDiv]").length)`  should be 1

Comment: @JeromyFrench Hi Jeromy, `HTML` is added to the **OP**. Im not familiar with jsfiddle or codepen. I can upload my .css as well if that is what you want. But as already said, this same .css file worked just 2 days ago just fine. And even if i delete it from the project now, the problem isnt fixed.

Comment: @freedomn-m `console.log` gives me **1** indeed (-underfiend underneath it). Ok i thought that hidden stands for elements, thanks for clarifying. 4 hidden messages are about console suggesting to change some `#id`s of my input fields. I dont think this is what is causing my problem

Comment: `$("body").ready(function () {` why do you have that inside document ready?

Comment: @freedomn-m  @JeromyFrench  Note that i have same-exact `html` and `css` file in separate folder (outside my current project) and they work perfectly fine when they use same `script.js`

Comment: @epascarello This is what i use to say 'when body is ready, do the `loadAll` function. `loadAll` function consist of 2 $.getJSON requests, one fills created` <table>` element and fills it with data from my database (appended to `#dataDiv`), other one fills my dropdownlist for Festival's location.

Comment: There is no body ready.... when the document is ready, you are good.

Comment: debug `console.log($("#searchDiv").length, $("#createEditDiv").length, $("#logoutDiv").length);` Did it find the elements?

Comment: @epascarello is that to check they exist?  Or check for duplicate IDs?  You probably know, but just FYI `$("#id")` will always be 0 or 1 (never >1), eg https://jsfiddle.net/e4f05ow6/

Comment: @epascarello This **debug** returned **1, 1, 1** so yes it found the elements. Edit: I just had to restart my computer, i loaded the project built it and ran the index.cshtml. It works now. I've no idea what was this all about.

Comment: @freedomn-m because it is easier to look at the length than to inspect objects....

Comment: Sounds like you are cached.... set up your developer tools to not cache when open.

Comment: @epascarello more about if there are 2 with the same id (already checked above) then `$("#id").hide()` will *only* hide the first one, which could be the cause of the one being looked at not being hidden (it's not in this case)